# docker-compose.yml - configs section: Additional property content is not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  test:
    image: busybox:latest
    configs:
      - source: cfg
        target: /opt/cfg.json
        mode: "0644"
configs:
  cfg:
    content: "{}"
```

`docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up`

```bash
validating /opt/docker-compose.yml: configs.cfg Additional property content is not allowed
```

Docker documentation on these docker-compose.yml sections:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/08-configs/#example-2
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#long-syntax

Latest docker release is installed from official Docker apt repo. Versions:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.7
 API version:       1.43
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.7
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
Docker Compose version v2.21.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker Compose 2.21.0 does not support this feature - you'll need 2.23.0 at least, if not 2.23.1.

See discussion at https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/pull/429

Comment: Thank you! This helped.

Though I do not understand, why didn't they upgrade compose specification version for this config sections.

Comment: Yes, this would be rather helpful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

And just to help somebody avoid unnecessary googling.

Upgrading compose plugin installed using official docker apt repo:

```bash
COMPOSE_VERSION="v2.23.3"
apt purge docker-compose-plugin
curl -SL "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-linux-x86_64" -o /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
chmod a+rx /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```